# Text to Columns formatting issues with Date/Time

Tags: excel, datetime

I am trying to figure out if this is an Excel bug or just a formatting issue.  So I have a column with a date and time in the format `m/d/yyy h:m AM/PM` (ie. `10/21/2015 2:21:00 PM`), and am trying to split it into two individual columns: one with the date and one with the time.  I tried using fixed width first, but ended up using delimited just so I could split it exactly where I wanted.

For some reason when it splits the two up, the actual value for time changes.  I will end up with one column with the date and a time of 12am (`10/21/2015 12:00 AM`) and one column with the initial time minus 12 hours (`2:21:00 AM`).... Trying to figure out why there is still a time value in the date column and why the time value changes.  Ideally I want to have a column with `10/21/2015` and another with `2:21:00 PM`.

I've tried changing the format of the initial date/time combination etc. and it keeps on subtracting 12 hours from the initial time when it splits.

Has anybody experienced or heard of similar issues?

Comment: This happens because what you see as a large text string is actually understood by Excel to be a number. Excel takes the date as an integer (which is equal to 1 day for each day after Jan 1 1900), and tacks on the time as a decimal. When you split the text, it now sees a "date integer" on one side, and a "time decimal" on the other. When it formats the "time decimal", it still thinks that it's a date-time combo, for Jan 1 1900.

Comment: it sounds like it may not be recognizing the AM / PM (at least by your example). If the time is originally 2:21:00 AM. Does it still subtract 12 hours? Or only when the time is PM?

Comment: Additionally, splitting on the space as the delimiter is stripping off the AM/PM from the time. Anything that had a PM becomes an AM because nothing is AM.

Comment: Have you considered going into the computer's system regional settings and making a permanent change to a `mm/dd/yyyy` short date so that you can use the fixed width without error?

Comment: Alright thanks, I got it to work but I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do it.  I formatted the initial date/time column as a number and got the value 42298.597917.  Then I used fixed width to split it just before the decimal point, resulting in one column (date) with 42298 and another column (time) with .59791666.  I then changed the format of the date column and got the correct date (10/10/2015) and the time column recorded the correct time (2:21:00 PM).  Works for now, but might have to use VBA to automate the process...

Comment: @ScottHoltzman it only subtracted 12 hrs for PM times.  For instance 3:30 AM would give you 3:30 AM after splitting it, but 4:40 PM would give you 4:40 AM after splitting...odd

Comment: Its possible to just use formulas in the 2 cells right next to the data to get what you want. In the first column you can strip out the date and the second, the time, and formatting accordingly. You can use `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and / or `Mid` and use the `" "` as the delimiter in a `FIND` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is confusing, for example *I tried using fixed width first, but ended up using delimited just so I could split it exactly where I wanted.* seems back-to-front, but you have a datetime value for  October 21, 2015 14:21 hrs, want that as a date in one column and `02:21:00 PM` in the next and your environment is `UK style` (ie day before month).

IF so Text to Columns may be as confusing as helpful. Format the date column as date (to suit) and the time column as `hh:mm:ss AM/PM` (or similar) and the following formulae may suit, assuming your datetime value is in A1:

For date:  `=INT(A1)`
For time:  `=MOD(A1,1)`

Comment: I ended up using the method I commented above, with a little VBA--thanks for the input though!  I'll maybe try this and keep it in the arsenal for future reference.